# Creating a new tag for Julia language

Tags: support, tags

I wanted to create a new tag for Julia language, which already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/julia-lang/info) in Stack Overflow. But, as I do not have a question in order to create a tag, I wanted to know how do I do it.

Update: So, there seems to be a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/does-julia-have-any-hope-of-sticking-in-the-statistical-community) on Julia, on which I have added the tag and thus, created it. (https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/julia-lang/info)

Comment: Leaving aside the specifics of this case; as a general principle, there's really no need to create tags before you have any questions to apply them to.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.  Seems like there is already a tag named julia (thanks for the edit.) on this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/does-julia-have-any-hope-of-sticking-in-the-statistical-community

But, do you think it should be julia-lang instead of julia (the reverse remap of the existing one)?

Comment: We have `r` (the most popular tag on the site), `matlab`, `sas`, `spss`, `c++`, `c#` etc ... so the `julia` tag fits with those while `julia-lang` does not. [In fact until you made `julia-lang`, there was not even a single language-name tag with  `-lang` in it. It's probably best to avoid breaking the local convention unless there's some level of agreement here on meta.]

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks for clarifying. Totally agree with you. And the fact that unnecessarily creating tags when there is no demand is also a very sensible point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always thought that tags are a very important part of keeping the content on CV well organized.  If there is a tag that really should exist to facilitate that task, you should create it.  That said, @Glen-b's point resonates here: if there aren't any questions whose content needs to be indexed by a given tag, there isn't really any need for that tag to exist (yet).

Also, be aware that it a tag exists on only one thread for a certain period of time (I think it's six months), the SE system will automatically delete it.  The idea is the same: there isn't really a set of information related to that topic that needs to be held together by the tag.  Please don't add it to extra threads just to make the tag stick, but search around, there are probably more relevant threads that could be connected.  If there aren't, the tag really should go; it can always be re-created in the future when it does become needed.